# Match or not not matching all the projected results - Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a mongo query that projects what I ned accordingly.
When I lookup to another collection (table), I want to ensure all the previous projected results do not match anything in the new collection I am looking into.

The projected results are as follows:

```
[
  { _id: 5d2fe82c4bd12894218deeb2, result: '5d3f6e86f8e09c10c4258c64' },
  { _id: 5d2fe90c4bd12894218deeb3, result: '5d3f6e9ff8e09c10c4258c68' }
]
```

After the projected result, bellow is the lookup query:

```
{$lookup:{
    from:'Room',
    let:{result:'$result'},
    pipeline:[{$match:{$expr:{$and:[ {$ne:['$$result','$host_id']}, {$ne:['$host_id',myId]} ]}}}],
    as:'publicHostings'
            }},
{$unwind:'$publicHostings'}
```

The lookup query generates the following:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5d2fe90c4bd12894218deeb3,
    result: '5d3f6e9ff8e09c10c4258c68',
    publicHostings: {
      _id: 5e03daaaf2496202ae4eb7c1,
      host_id: '5d3f6e86f8e09c10c4258c64',
      host_name: 'Z',
    }
  }
]
```

One can see that in one of the projected result that is generated early, matches the host_id. So it should not generate the final result.

**Actually it would generate one more document but I have a check ({$ne:['$host_id',myId]})

I want to try $elemMatch but I do not know how to do it with pipeline.
As usual, thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you please provide some dummy data and expected result?

Comment: `$elemMatch` makes sense when you run your query against arrays. In this case it looks like you're trying to compare fields of string type. What is the value of `myId` variable ?

Comment: @mickl its a string type that looks like 5d3f6e94f8e09c10c4258c66. Do you know how to incorporate $elemMatch inside a lookup query?

Comment: @PatrickAdjei there is an alternative syntax for `$lookup` but I need to see the reason why you want to use `$elemMatch`. Could you explain which part of your `$lookup` query is an array ?

Comment: @mickl I don't need to use $elemMatch, I just don't know any other way so I wanted to try $elemMatch. I unwind 'publicHostings'. Before that it's an array of object. Could you please provide the alternate syntax so I can try it out.

Comment: @PatrickAdjei you can try `$anyElementTrue` with `$map` but my guess is that something is wrong with `myId` variable or we need more details since `{$ne:['$$result','$host_id']}` part of your query looks valid

Comment: @mickl when I remove {$ne:['$host_id',myId]}, I simply get more documents. {$ne:['$$result','$host_id']} is indeed valid I think but I want any result ('5d3f6e9ff8e09c10c4258c68', '5d3f6e86f8e09c10c4258c64') value seen in the lookup to not be printed. So essentially, because result has '5d3f6e86f8e09c10c4258c64', The lookup above (in the problem description) should not be generated since the host_id has this value '5d3f6e86f8e09c10c4258c64' (same as result). However, it generates it either way because it compares result: '5d3f6e9ff8e09c10c4258c68' to host_id: '5d3f6e86f8e09c10c4258c64'

Comment: It generates it because they aren't equal to each other. Again it should not generate it because **5d3f6e86f8e09c10c4258c64** is also seen in result. Looking at **$anyElementTrue** with **$map**, I still need to do a lookup. Would you know the syntax by any chance?

Comment: @PatrickAdjei this is why I don't follow: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vkmNEUxzUHn Could you provide more data and show how are you getting `publicHostings` for given values

Comment: @mickl I added more data and comments in the configuration and query part. Essentially, the result I would like to have is an empty array ( [ ] ). If you check in the comments, I point to you where the matches are happening for an empty array to occur. Obvisously, the query is not doing the job and take off the comment (be carful of the commas). https://mongoplayground.net/p/z9_oRqLLUyW

Comment: @mickl I have another approach. Let me know if I should ask another question instead